# Retrieve geometry type (point/line/polygon) from OL3 feature

Tags: openlayers

How do I tell whether an OL3 feature is a point, line, or polygon? I need to highlight features on mouseover, and the style required is different for points, so I need to be able to tell which geometry type a feature is, so that I can apply the correct style.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it: feature.getGeometry().getType()

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.html#.GeometryType) is the link to the official documentation of OL3 API for getType(). Its not available in the list of functions defined for Geometry.